# How can I import selected functions from a module as an object in ES2015?

Tags: javascript, optimization, ecmascript-6

I want something like this

```
import { stuffA, stuffB } as myStuff from 'stuff'
```

I know this won't work, you know what I mean with this code, do you?
Actually there's something similiar in ES2015 like

```
import * as myStuff from 'stuff'
```

but I only want part of the content from stuff

and I know this would work

```
import { stuffA, stuffB } from 'stuff'
const myStuff = { stuffA, stuffB }
```

but this approach is ugly isn't it?

And I want the result to be like

```
myStuff = {
  stuffA: stuffA,
  stuffB: stuffB
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it's possible. What's so wrong with

```
import { stuffA, stuffB } from 'stuff'
const myStuff = { stuffA, stuffB }
```

anyway?

Comment: as i have many functions in stuff module, and import like 60% of them, each time i edit line one, i have to modify line two as well, it's ugly and seems wrong.

Comment: @Liang So why don't you import the whole module (with `*`)?

Comment: but i won't need the rest of the them, i just don't understand why we can import selected functions as functions but cannot put the selected ones in an object in a single line of code.

Comment: @Liang Well, you should ask people who make ECMAScript standard.